# Did Vader reach out to the Force to reacquire his lost potential?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, armor

Vader was pretty much discarded once his Midichlorian count diminished after being mauled by Obi but couldn't he reach out to the Force and reacquire his lost potential? He was in a great position to do so, his master being Darth Sidious, after all, Midichlorian meddling was Sidious' master specialty, and he said he learned everything he could from him prior to killing him.

EDIT: Edited to be different from the other question, the main topic here is if Vader with the help of Sidious could or did reach out to the Force to reacquire his potential, Vader at the height of his power in the suit was described as more powerful than Anakin ever was, so we can assume he somehow achieved a portion of his true potential, Sidious recognized these newfound powers of Vader and even made a new set of armour without the limitations of his current suit because he proved he was a worthy enough successor.

Comment: Do not drastically edit a question that has already garnered an answer, making the existing answer a non-answer. Open a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Darth Vader's cybernetic suit of armour was also his life-support system. From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vader's_armor):

> The armor's belt and chest plate held the controls for the life support system, ensuring that Vader's body received enough oxygen, nutrients, and medicine; through this system, Vader could endure nearly any environment, including the vacuum of space.

And:

> The helmet created Vader's menacing growl due to his natural voice being very weak from vocal-cord damage, and contained neural needles that painfully connected with the top of Vader's skull and spine, to form one interconnected unit. Without these, Vader could not use his artificial limbs. The armor had ten protective layers, while Vader had four artificial limbs as a result of his injuries on Mustafar and at the hand of Dooku on Geonosis.

Vader was encased in the armour after grave injuries sustained in a lightsaber duel with Obi-Wan Kenobi:

> A DD-13 Medical Assistant Droid fitted him with cybernetic implants while a 2-1B surgical droid picked away any remaining chars of clothing and flesh from the Dark Lord's body. An FX-9 Medical droid supplied Vader with blood transfusions during the surgery. Vader required a permanent breathing apparatus, a result of his encounter with the flames, altering his voice into a deep growl.

Further:

> Darth Vader wore the armor for over two decades, until his redemption and death. He initially hated the armor, but after living with it for several years, he embraced how it isolated him from the rest of the galaxy, allowing him to concentrate on becoming a pure instrument of the dark side.

Comment: Does this explain why he couldn't "reach out to the Force", as the question asked, to re-acquire his lost potential?